# Connection to database not created after setup created

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I had developed `C# application`. and used external tool for themes.

Before creating setup for this application it works fine. and no problem in database connection.

But after creating setup for this application and installing it, connection to database not created.

I have used `app.config` file for getting connection string. Am I missing something when creating setup or the problem due to external theme?

My app.config code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> <connectionStrings> 
<add name="connectionStrings" connectionString="Data Source=SUMEET-PC\SQLSERVERNEW; Initial Catalog=ClothShop;User Id=sa;Password=123;" /> 
</connectionStrings> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Post app.config code here.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="connectionStrings"
      connectionString="Data Source=SUMEET-PC\SQLSERVERNEW;Initial Catalog=ClothShop;User Id=sa;Password=123;" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>

Comment: Log the connection string to a log file before connecting and make sure that it is getting the correct connection string.